# Understanding .ear packaging

Tags: maven

I'm new to maven-2 and i use it with Netbeans-7.3.1 so i hope this question is not a dumb one.

I have used maven to create an EAR project which include 2 EJB modules. The ear is also  a module in an aggregating pom project with pom packaging. After clean and build the aggregating pom project and When i explored the generated ear artifact in the repository i found in META-INF of the ear and in the META-INF of the 2 ejb's  a folder which contains the packake structure of the module which contains a pom.xml and pom.properties.

I wonder what's the use of those files? can i remove them without affecting the artifact?
And one last question, is there other way to export the aggregator pom project with it's sub-modules rather than going to maven repository and get the ear from there(Using Netbeans)?

Comment: why do you want to remove these files, what is the motivation?

Comment: just need to know what they are used for. If no meaning for them then i don't prefer to send them to production

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove all maven meta-data from META-INF directory *(like pom.xml and pom.properties)*.

The main file in *.EAR (Enterprise archive) is **application.xml** (application server uses this file during deployment).
`Maven` generates appication.xml file with `maven-ear-plugin`.

So, all required data in **.EAR/META-INF*:

```
/META-INF/application.xml
/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

all other data you can remove